# Attempting to install Stable Diffusion via Python

Tags: python, pip, stable-diffusion

I've trawled through stack overflow, several youtube videos and can't for the life of me work this out.

I've unpackaged and pulled from git, all files are where they need to be as far as the installation for Stable Diffusion goes - but when I go to run I get two errors, one being the pip version. I upgraded via '`pip install --upgrade pip`' and though the version updated, I'm still getting the below error.

The other issue is that pytorch doesn't seem to have installed. I've added it to the requirements.txt and run '`pip install -r requirements.txt`' which doesn't seem to work either. I also downloaded 1.12.1+cu113 and ran `pip install "path/"` and received the error "ERROR: torch-1.12.1+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Error received below:

stderr: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.1+cu113 (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1+cu113

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 22.3 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\STABLE\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried my best to be self-sufficient so I'm putting it to the people who may know how to help.

Comment: *"ERROR: torch-1.12.1+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."* means that either your Python is not of version 3.9 or is not 64-bit. To check: `python --version`, `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`, `pip --version`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest methods to install SD is with Automatic1111
https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui

Instructions on this page in a section titled "Automatic Installation on Windows" (since you're using windows paths in your post)

1. Install Python 3.10.6, checking "Add Python to PATH" Install git.
2. Download the stable-diffusion-webui repository, for example by running git clonehttps://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui.git.
3. Place model.ckpt in the models directory (see dependencies for where to
   get it).
4. (Optional) Place GFPGANv1.4.pth in the base directory,
   alongside webui.py (see dependencies for where to get it).
5. Run webui-user.bat from Windows Explorer as normal, non-administrator,
   user.

This is much easier and improved from the early days of Automatic and Stable Diffusion itself.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with python 3.8. I install python3.10 and fixed.
For mac:
brew install python@3.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).